# Why often is used a varistor 7D471K for 220-240vac surge protection rather than a lower nominal voltage one?

Tags: surge-protection, varistor

In my "supposedly" surge protected power stripe there is a varistor for surge protection configured to simply short-circuit the entrance wires in case of surge.

Checking the model it's a **MOV-7D471K** that on Mouser is reported having the following specs:

```
Voltage Rating DC: 517 VDC 

Clamping Voltage: 775 V 

Diameter: 7 mm 

Peak Surge Current: 1.2 kA 

Surge Energy Rating: 30 J 

Capacitance: 105 pF
```

This has confused me since these values seems to me too high considering that is supposed to protect a 220-240vac max line (European domestic distribution range), and searching on web seems that is often used this MOV for domestic surge protection.

I have seen also that **MOV-10D221K** seems having values more near to 220-240vac:

```
Voltage Rating DC: 242 VDC 

Clamping Voltage: 360 V 

Diameter: 10 mm 

Peak Surge Current: 2.5 kA 

Surge Energy Rating: 32 J 

Capacitance: 450 pF
```

Why is used MOV-7D471K rather than MOV-10D221K (or some other, suggestion are welcome)? Is my power stripe bad configured or I'm missing something?

Comment: These devices have a limited Joule discharge lifetime and devices have a much higher transient tolerance for insulation Vcm breakdown and differential Vdiff * t from inductive integration  So too low will wearout too fast.  These parameters are unknown like the transients but they exist so use what experts have discovered or do your research on all devices for what is needed to protect.  Also Vp is 360Vp on 240Ac rms would be a really bad idea to clamp the grid voltage (poof)

Comment: When a vacuum cleaner or any other inductive load connected to AC mains is switched off, the sudden collapse of the motor's magnetic field can very briefly cause a voltage spike across the mains. While unlikely to raise it by hundreds of volts, it *could* raise it by dozens of volts. In the case of the MOV-10D221K, it's clamping voltage is so near the peak value of 240vAC (x1.414=340vDC) it would clamp, forcing a circuit breaker to open, *even if the motor is not connected to this surge strip.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be reading the specs wrong. A 10D221K would blow up when connected to 240VAC mains as mains have about 340V peak voltage, and so something else must be used.

10D221K can handle max 140 V RMS or 180V DC, and starts conducting 1mA at voltages between 198 and 242 V. It will clamp to 360 V, when 25 A is flowing. It just is not compatible with 240 VAC mains.

7D471K can candle max 300V RMS or 385 VDC, starts conducting 1 mA between 423 and 517 V, can clamp to 775 V when 10 A is flowing. No problem at 240 VAC mains.

Comment: you are right I have read it wrongly